# Django-tables2: Change attribute for multiple columns in __init__()

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, constructor, django-tables2

I can't figure out how to change attribute for multiple columns in one for loop.

I want to set `orderable=False` to multiple columns. The only way which works is to explicitely define all these columns so I can add `orderable=False` to constructor.

```
class PizzaTable(tables.Table):

    class Meta:
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap-responsive.html'
        model = Pizza
        fields = ['created', 'ham', 'olives', 'corn', 'price',]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        unorderable_columns = ['ham', 'olives', 'corn',]
        for column in unorderable_columns:
            self.columns[column].orderable = False
```

This raises:

> can't set attribute

It has to be able to do it somehow, otherwise I would have to specify all of those columns:

```
ham = tables.Column(accessor='ham',orderable=False)
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @schwobaseggl Thanks, it seems to work this way! Feel free to add an answer and I will mark it answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.columns` contains instances of `BoundColumn`. These have some additional knowledge (e.g. their own attribute name within the table they are used in) and refer to the actual defined `Column` instance via `self.column`. They also expose that column's `orderable` attribute via a setter-less property, hence the error. In order to dynamically change that property, you have to set the attribute on the underlying column:

```
 self.columns[column].column.orderable = False
 # instead of 
 # self.columns[column].orderable = False
```